# How to make a copy slice of struct

Tags: go

I have a slice of struct. I am trying to copy this slice to new variable since my original slice changes a lot
model for sheet

```
type Timesheet struct {
    ID              *int64     `json:"id"`
    TimestampStart  *time.Time `json:"timestampStart"`
    TimestampEnd    *time.Time `json:"timestampEnd"`
}


SheetArrayCopy := make([]models.Sheet, len(sheetList))
copy(SheetArrayCopy, SheetList)
//several steps which goes through SheetList and changes the value of sheetList
```

However when I change the value in `sheetList,` the values of `SheetArrayCopy` also changes.

Comment: Most likely you just copy the pointers, but not the pointed values. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: That'd also be my assumption. `copy` is a shallow copy, it's going to copy the items from one slice to the other but not recursively, so if any of those items contains a pointer the pointer itself is copied, the pointee doesn't get duplicated. As a result if the pointee is modified that's going to affect all copies.

Comment: Here's a demonstration of the issue: https://play.golang.org/p/9-_42Bb7Msu

Answer (score 1):

From your question and @Masklinn example link. I can see that you set value by using *pointer (address that pointer points to) which means set the value of that address to the new value.

There is nothing to do with

> copy

Which is doing exactly which it means. And in this case, it clone the value of the fields' pointers which is pointing to the address of the fields' values.

The problem is the way you use and set value of the pointers.

There are 3 ways, to avoid the problem you mentioned about.

1. Write your custom clone slice which init new structs and clone only the **values** from original slice to the new.
2. Still using the clone, but when you set the value of the fields, set the fields' pointers to the new address. Others slices' items pointers still point to the old value.
3. Don't use pointer if you don't have any special reason.

You can ref to my code which is the demonstration of my answer.

https://play.golang.org/p/-pIgEDEr-hI

Link about the pointer which points out directly about how to use pointer.
https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. I am aware of point 2 and 3. just wanted to ensure there are not any prebuilt function for these, since, it seems like a pretty common scenario for reasl world scenarios. I have a good reason for using pointers(since i need null values for insertion to db. an primitive type dont allow those)

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can covert that back to json and unmarsal that json to its new destination.

Comment: Please provide an answer with complete details. Your answer should be clearly understandable to anyone who'll be reading the question in the future.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. But the solution is correct, but I was hoping for a go-specific solution, which doesnt use json.